# vb.net data reader using text change event

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to create a textbox which contents are validated every time the text in it changes. And an image is displayed beside the textbox if it is correct and another image shows up if its not correct. Pretty much like ajax.

Heres the method which I called from the class.

```
Public Sub read1()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE Name='" & name & "'"
    Try
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim n As String
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            n = rdr("Name").ToString
            Form1.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\Public\Check-icon.png")



        Else
            Form1.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\Public\Delete-icon.png")

        End If


        Catch ex As Exception
```

And here the event which calls for the method:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        x.name = TextBox1.Text
        x.read1()

    End Sub

    End Try

End Sub
```

Problem is, the method seems to be only called once. And the first image that was displayed stays the same even after inputting a data which does not exist in the database.
I'm connecting this program to a mysql database using odbc. Can you help me determine whats the problem and how to fix it?

Heres the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a DataReader object, you have to call the `Read` method before you can access the row.  I think it would need to look like the following.  I am guessing at the VB.Net syntax and method name, but I am reasonably sure it would be simply rdr.Read.

```
    If rdr.HasRows Then
        rdr.Read
        n = rdr("Name").ToString
```

**Edit** In addition, you probably need to close the DataReader. Some .NET data providers allow only a single reader to be open at a time on a given connection, and it seems likely that the ODBC provider is one of them.  Without a specific call to close it, you would be relying on the garbage collector to clean it up:

```
rdr.Close
```

And while this has nothing to do with the question directly, you should probably use a parameterized query to avoid an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Did you step through it in the debugger to see what it is doing?  I was assuming that without the .Read call, the retrieval of the value from the rdr object was causing an exception and, thus, skipping the load of the image.

Comment: @Mark .Read is not required; .HasRows should be all this is required.

Comment: @Tim, You are correct that HasRows is all that is necessary to determine if data exists.  But the OP code is retrieving data, which requires a call to the .Read method.

Comment: @Mark. Sorry are are quite right. However, the OP code (at least in the example) does not use n so n = rdr("Name").ToString is not required.

Comment: @Tim, I did notice that too.  I am thinking/assuming/guessing that the code was trimmed quite a bit before the post.  Nonetheless, I am somewhat confident (between 78% and 87.2%) that my edits about the closing of the reader are closer to the actual problem.  Being a programmer is fun, but also somewhat tedious.  I woke up in the middle of the night for no apparent reason and had the thought out of the blue (or black since it was dark) that the basic problem was that there were multiple reader objects open on the connection.

Comment: @Mark. I know the feeling all to well. You could be right about needing to close the datareader. I would put it in a Using ... End Using block. Which we got some feed back from @user225269. A simple step through the debugger, as you suggested, should quickly see what is going on.